# Is there any way to speed up a DataGridView Remove?

Tags: c#, datagridview, row

I'm working with large sets of data and I'm storing them in a DataGridView so that the user can see that data in an application and manipulate it before it is saved into a database. Nothing is saved into the database until the user hits the save button.

The user has the ability to delete multiple rows by pressing the delete key, this works just fine if its just a few rows. What if they wanted to delete a couple thousand? It takes way too long to remove that large number of rows.

This is how I'm currently removing them:

```
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.SelectedRows)
       dgv.Rows.Remove(row);
```

Is there any way that I could just remove all of those rows in one fell swoop? Basically something like the Clear function, but I give it a list of rows to remove.

Comment: `I'm working with large sets of data` - You may want to see [this short clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3Y6DnFpHCA)

Answer (score -1):

Try disabling GUI Update using SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout:

```
dgv.SuspendLayout();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.SelectedRows)
{
    dgv.Rows.Remove(row);
}
dgv.ResumeLayout();
```

Comment: That didn't really change anything. I'm really looking for how to remove more than just one row at once. Thanks for the suggestion though!